# Filter by month in sequelize from createdAt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have raw query like this

```
SELECT trx.WarehouseId, pr.CategoryId, pr.id AS productId, ct.category_name, pr.product_name, pr.description, trx_items.price_per_item AS price, trx_items.quantity,
trx_items.price_per_item * trx_items.quantity AS total, wr.warehouse_name, trx_items.createdAt
FROM transactionitems AS trx_items
JOIN transactions AS trx ON trx.id = trx_items.TransactionId
JOIN products AS pr ON pr.id = trx_items.ProductId
JOIN categories AS ct ON ct.id = pr.CategoryId
JOIN warehouses as wr ON wr.id = trx.WarehouseId
WHERE MONTH(trx_items.createdAt) = 2;
```

it'll return all data in February, so i want to convert raw query into sequlize but i don't know how to get month in sequlize. i have sequelize code like this

```
 const { createdAt } = req.query
            if (createdAt) {
                const findDataFilter = await db.Transaction.findAndCountAll({
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: db.Warehouse,
                        },
                        {
                            model: db.TransactionItem,
                            include: [
                                {
                                    model: db.Product,
                                    include: [
                                        {
                                            model: db.Category,
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                            ],
                            required: true,
                            where: sequelize.fn(
                                "MONTH",
                                sequelize.col("createdAt")
                            ),
                        },
                    ],
                    
                })
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Get data filtered",
                    data: findDataFilter.rows,
                    dataCount: findDataFilter.count,
                })
            }
```

it return "Column 'createdAt' in on clause is ambiguous". i'm new in sequelize so idk what method to use. if i write `where: {createdAt}` this return nothing

i want to filter by month in table TransactionItem but with sequelize.

Comment: What version of sequelize are you using?

Comment: Can you test like this?```sequelize.where("MONTH",sequelize.col("createdAt"), 2)``` If it works, let me know, so I can post a more complete answer.

Comment: @GabrielNexT i'm using v6.25

Comment: @GabrielNexT how to use that? i try use like this `where: [sequelize.where("MONTH",sequelize.col("createdAt"), 2)]` and it return "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')",  and when i try using `attributes:[sequelize.where("MONTH",sequelize.col("createdAt"), 2)]` it return "s.replace is not a function". sorry i'm new to sequelize

Answer (score 0):

I think `createdAt` exists in more tables than `transactionitems`, that's why the error is "column ambiguos".

You should specify the table before the column like this:

```
sequelize.fn(
  "MONTH",
  sequelize.col("TransactionItem.createdAt")
)
```